# Copy and get the first level of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the first-level lists of elements without the child elements below. So only `Program 1`, `Program 2`, `Program 3` and `Program 4` are the only items or elements I need to get.

Can't seem to find a solution on how I can accomplish it. This is just a sample code in the project I'm working and the markup cannot be edited to add specific classes.

```js
var menuContainer = $('<ul class="menu" />');

var nonDegMenu = $('#header a[href$="/programs"]').next().clone(),
  nonDegList = $('li', nonDegMenu),
  nonDeg = $('#footer .programs-menu .non-degree'),
  items = menuContainer.appendTo(nonDeg),
  course = nonDegList.slice(0);

//Append Non Degree Courses
items.append(course);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/programs">Programs</a>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 1</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program A</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program B</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program C</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program D</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 2</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program E</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program F</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program G</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program H</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 3</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program I</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program J</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program K</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program L</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Programs 4</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program M</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program N</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program O</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" >Program P</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div id="footer" >
    <div class="programs-menu">
        <div  class="non-degree">
          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the child selector, `>`, to get the child `ul` elements and remove them from the cloned `ul`. Try this:

```js
var $menuContainer = $('<ul class="menu" />');
var $nonDegMenu = $('#header a[href$="/programs"]').next().clone();
var $items = $menuContainer.appendTo('#footer .programs-menu .non-degree');
  
$nonDegMenu.find('li > ul').remove();
$items.append($nonDegMenu);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="header">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/programs">Programs</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Programs 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Program A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program D</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Programs 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Program E</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program F</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program G</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program H</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Programs 3</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Program I</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program J</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program K</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program L</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Programs 4</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Program M</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program N</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program O</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program P</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="programs-menu">
    <div class="non-degree"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the insights, would like to ask is it possible to `slice` the elements. Lets say I only want `Programs 2`, `Programs 3` and `Programs 4`. Excluding `Programs 1` from the lists. Adding the jQuery `slice` inside the append doesn't seem to work `items.append(nonDegMenu.slice(0,3));`

Comment: Yep, you can use `$nonDegMenu.remove('li:first')` to do that before the `append()` call

Comment: Thank you again, but is there a way to chain it like lets say `$nonDegMenu.remove('li:first').slice(1,3)` instead of using `(`li:first`)`. It might come to a point where I need a range of elements that I need to get instead of adding `:first` or `last` to exclude them

Comment: No. As you're attempting to slice the `ul`, not the `li`. You seem intent on using `slice()` when it really isn't needed, and is far too rigid

Comment: I might need to use it in the end for example I have 7 items in the lists and I only want to get items #4 till #7.

Comment: In that case you can use a combination of `eq()`, `gt()` and `lt()`